# Analyzing potential threats from re-directs

Tags: malware, web-browser, url-redirection

I just clicked a link on pinterest to take me to the source website. Upon clicking, it took me to the following 5 links:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bishkek0303/decorative-graphic-design-element-in-oriental-style-sun-moon-clouds-stars-vector-hand-drawn-illustration-com-imagens.html

maindomain333.top/hairstyles.html

https://t.co/QunkuSWPn4?amp=1

https://www.tasikardi.net/?redirect_to=random

https://tasikardi.net/pastel-eyeliner-way-of-adding-soft-colours/
```

What can one do to ensure no threats were posed during these re-directs?
Aside from 'scanning' the websites with [Nortons Website Check tool](https://safeweb.norton.com/)

Is there anything to look out for specifically in the network logs of the browser developer tools for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanning the resulting page ***that you see*** will do little to analyse the threat. What you need to do is to analyse what happens when you click the link and the code that is run by your browser in each step.

To do that, you need to run the URL through a malware analysis sandbox. There are several types, some free, some commercial, some local, some in the cloud.

The government of Estonia has placed a powerful malware sandbox online *for free*: https://cuckoo.ee/

There is also [Joesandbox](https://www.joesandbox.com/), and multiple vendors with their own options.